# Negate Public Sub Macro

Tags: vba, public

I have inherited a user form where I have been asked to add a macro so data can be imported at a click of a button rather than manually added in, This is fine however when I've tested the macro via stepping through, it 'jumps' to a Public sub macro which was already in the user form. I think it maybe due to switching between workbooks which causes the public sub to attempt to run.  This is my macro which imports the data

```
 Sub Importdata()

 Dim mywb As Workbook

Set mywb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'File Directory Where Data comes From

FilePath = "\\xxxxxx "

VM = mywb.Sheets("feeder").Range("G1")

Set x = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & VM & ".xls")


x.Sheets("Main Journals").Cells.Copy
mywb.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It gets to the line **Set x = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & VM & ".xls")** and then it 'jumps' to this macro which was already in the inherited work and my macro falls over.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.BneRemoveOracleMenu
End Sub
```

How Do I negate this? Many Thanks.

Comment: You have an event handler. It runs when the event happens. If you don't want that, don't have an event handler. If you know exact circumstances in which you want to not execute the handler, either check for these circumstances from inside the handler, or set `EnableEvents` to `False` before doing actions that trigger the event.

Comment: GSerg thats absolutely great, worked a charm. Thanks very much for the help